# How to restrict property declaration while creating a FromGroup on angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to restrict property declaration while creating a FromGroup.
I have tried this way.

1. Create a type like this:

[image]

After that I have used this on FromGroup Generic type like this:
[image]

But in this case I am getting this error: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'`

Is it really possible to restrict FormGroup ?

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form type should be like this.

```
type FormType = { 
    id: FormControl<number | null>;
 }
```

If you don't want to allow null values, then you can do this:

```
type FormType = { 
    id: FormControl<number>;
 }

assetDeAllocationForm = new FormGroup<FormType>({
   id: new FormControl(0, { nonNullable: true})
});
```

Comment: Sadly this is still how it works and there is no comment suggesting that there will be something more useful soon